# Filtering products in GridView, OnItemClick passes different product details

Tags: java, android, gridview, filter, onitemclicklistener

I'm using `GridView` to display products. Im my custom adapter class I implemented filter search which allows me to give wanted results. After adding `OnItemClick` I realised that the clicked item gives me wrong details when in filtering mode.

To my mind it has something to do with `ViewHolder` which is implemented in `customadapter` and sends user to wrong item activity. Why? Let's have a look at this picture:
[image: Strange beahaviour]
It represents two situation 
1)when activity is launched and `gridview` displays all entries by default 
2)when filter search was used and shows the results

Here is some part of my custom adapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getView: assigning all values to custom adapter");

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    Product product= productList.get(position);

    //Creating new fields
    if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_product_layout, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.productName = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.productPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.price);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    //Set up textviews and image
    viewHolder.productName.setText(product.getName());
    viewHolder.productPrice.setText(product.getPrice());

    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView productName;
    TextView productPrice;
}
```

And here is code for filter search, I keep it in the same main class (CustomAdapter):

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (customFilter == null) {
        customFilter = new CustomFilter();
    }
    return customFilter;
}

class CustomFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

        if (charSequence != null && charSequence.length() > 0) {
            charSequence = charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();

            List<Product> filters = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
                if (tempList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence)) {
                    Product product = new Product( tempList.get(i).getName(), tempList.get(i).getPrice());
                    filters.add(product);
                }
            }

            filterResults.count = filters.size();
            filterResults.values = filters;
        } else {
            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            filterResults.values = tempList;
        }

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        productList = (List<Product>) filterResults.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

`OnItemClick` code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {



    Product product = allProducts.get(i);
                String name = product.getName();
                String price = product.getPrice();

Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProductDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("price", price);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I want to get rid of misleading `OnItemClick` beahviour which launches details activity with wrong details.

Implementation of custom made search bar:

```
final EditText searchBar = findViewById(R.id.search_product);
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(this);
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: starting...");

    this.productAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

}
```

Clear button code:

```
//Clear search bar
    ImageView cancelClearSearch = findViewById(R.id.cancel_clear_search);
    cancelClearSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            searchBar.setText("");
            searchBar.clearFocus();

            //Hide keyboard
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchBar.getWindowToken(), 0);

            new DownloadProducts().execute();
        }
    });
```

Comment: code of click listener complete  implementation ?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
productList = (List<Product>) filterResults.values;
```

the list in adapter and in activity starts pointing to two separate lists in memory but the filtered data is in the list used by adapter so instead of assigning new list to `productList` use

```
productList.clear();
productList.addAll((List<Product>) filterResults.values);
```

or the alternative option is to retrieve the data from `adapterView` instance as

```
//Product product = allProducts.get(i);
Product product = (Product)adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
// get associated adapter with list view ^^^^^^^^^
// get the item from adapter, using position       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

To display the old list after clearing the search `edittext`, just apply the filter with empty string as

```
//Clear search bar
ImageView cancelClearSearch = findViewById(R.id.cancel_clear_search);
cancelClearSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        this.productAdapter.getFilter().filter("");
        searchBar.setText("");
        searchBar.clearFocus();

        //Hide keyboard
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchBar.getWindowToken(), 0);

        //new DownloadProducts().execute(); no need to download data again
    }
});
```

Comment: @Paveneet_Singh Alright but there is one more issue. If I stop filtering and all products disappear and nothing is shown after that. How can we change it to reload all products again?

Comment: @D.B. how do you stop filtering? mean stop typing in middle. could you explain it?

Comment: @Paveneet_Singh So basically, I start typing some letters let's say I type "s" so I get all products that have "s" in their name, when I add another letter for instance "h" it shows me all results that have "sh" in their names. I created button to clear the search and when I press it, the edittext is set to " " and a keyboard hides. I found the solution to implement new product download async task while pressing cancel button and it works, but I want to create more sophisticated way to do so.

Comment: Where should I put this code? I posted code for the clear button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168485/discussion-between-pavneet-singh-and-d-b).